# Use mathematical induction to prove that a function is divisible by 9

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, induction

I initially posted a question and thought that was the only one I was stuck on, but there's this other question too.

I think I kinda solved it, but I'm getting that it isn't divisible by 9. I'd like a confirmation please!

The question is as follows:

> Use mathematical induction to prove that $$5^{2n+1} - 21n + 31$$ is divisible by $9$ for $\forall n \geq 1$.

Comment: "I think I kinda solved it" - so please share with us what you did. I would be glad to see your progress.

Comment: I think it is divisible by 9, can you show us your calculations?

Comment: $5^{2n+1}\equiv(-1-3)^{2n+1}\equiv-1+(2n+1)(-3)\equiv-6n-4\equiv21n-31\pmod9$

Comment: I ended up solving it last night and falling asleep. I basically got the last line as 504k - 765 by subbing for 5^(2k+1) = 21k - 31. And that line is divisible by 9. So kinda similar to what @LearningMathematics did below, but we've never used mod.

Answer (score 1):

For $n = 1$,

$5^{2n+1} - 21n + 31 = 135$, which is divisible by 9.

Assume the claim hold for $n = k$.

When $n = k + 1$,

$5^{2(k+1)+1}−21(k+1)+31 \pmod9$

$\equiv 25(5^{2k+1})−21k + 10 \pmod9$

$\equiv  25(21k - 31) - 21k + 10 \pmod9$

$\equiv 9(56k) -31*25  + 10 \pmod9$

$\equiv 0 \pmod9$

Therefore the claim is true for all integer n $\ge 1$

Answer (score 0):

$5^{2n+1}-21n+31$ is divisible by $9$.

Here is a hint for the induction step:

$5^{2(n+1)+1}-21(n+1)+31=25(5^{2n+1}-21n+31)+504n-765$